# Что означает данная запись на c++ : #define FLT_EPSILON 1.19209290E-07F

Tags: c++, типы

Сама запись:

```
#define FLT_EPSILON         1.19209290E-07F
```

Что такое

```
#define
```

и имя я знаю, но что значит  1.19209290E-07F нет.
Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define FLT_EPSILON         1.19209290E-07F
```

это наследие си. На данный момент лучше писать так

```
const float FLT_EPSILON = 1.19209290E-07F;
```

В большинстве случаев эти записи эквивалентны по функционалу.

`#define` - это директива препроцессора, которая просто обозначает замену одного куска текста на другой. Препроцессор работает ещё до компилятора (хотя сейчас это происходит почти одним процессов) и иногда может давать чудесные результаты. К примеру, мой любимый

```
#define true false
```

и все вхождения true как слова будут заменены на false (`bool a = true;` будет заменено на `bool a = false;`, но true1 не будет.)

У define есть одна особенность - они ничего не знают о областях видимости и работают от места объявления и до конца файла. Именно поэтому, очень интересно наблюдать, как windows.h подменяет max/min и вызывает ошибки.

Хотя define и страшные, и ошибок много дают, но иногда они позволяют элегантно и красиво решить проблемы.

Буковка F в конце - это просто [литерал](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal). Такой себе способ уточнить тип переменной (ведь по умолчанию 1.0 - это double). В новом с++ появилась возможность создавать свои собственные [литералы](https://habr.com/post/140357/).

Comment: Вообще-то `const` это из совсем другой оперы. Использовать вместо `#define` можно не `const`, а `constexpr`.

Comment: Уже второй ответ, который называет `F` литералом. :) Литерал - это все число целиком.

Comment: уточняющий буква литерала

Comment: @freim а вот не нужен тут constexpr. От слова совсем. В общем случае, как показывает дизассемблер, компилятор будет делать хуже код.

Comment: @KoVadim, нужен здесь `constexpr` или не нужен это другой вопрос. Говорить, что `#define` и `const` эквивалентны по функционалу просто неверно. Даже `constexpr` не эквивалентен `#define` по функционалу, но там хоть какое-то соответствие есть.

Comment: На том уровне вопроса они эквивалентны. Да. я знаю, что макросами можно так делать, что не всякие шаблоны можно написать в эквивалент.

Comment: Спорить на тему "const vs #define" бесполезно вне контекста. Вполне может быть, что это было использовано в заголовочном файле, который возможно должен быть совместимым и с С. Переход на `const` для плавающего литерала не приведет к большим потерями в С, но тогда уж нужно `static const`.

Answer (score 2):

1.19209290E-07 - это число с плавающей точкой (1.19209290 * 10^-7), суффикс F в конце указывает, что число типа float

Comment: На случай, если спросившему не очевидно, вместо `-` там мог быть `+` (или ничего, что значит то же самое).